# Drag formula a vertically and horizontally in Excel

Tags: excel

I trying to populate the formula of distance between two points-shown in the image below-I want to be able to type the equation in one cell and drag it vertically and horizontally to populate the matrix. I tried to $, but it didn't give the desired results. Please see the image below as an illustration; it's an example. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Excel doesn't understand the reference to x1 and x2.  What you need to do first is type in the topmost cell coordinates like so:

`sqrt((D6-H6)^2+(E6-I6)^2)`

Then drag down from the corner of the cell containing the formula and Excel should extrapolate the forumla for you to populate the rest of the cells.  Also, you can also simply click on the cells to insert them into the formula instead of typing them in.

As you drag down, Excel should automatically repeat the formula by incrementing the row number by one for each row you drag the cursor to:
`sqrt((D7-H7)^2+(E7-I7)^2)`
`sqrt((D8-H8)^2+(E8-I8)^2)`
`sqrt((D9-H9)^2+(E9-I9)^2)`
...

**EDIT**

If you're doing matrix multiplication, this may not work smoothly for you.  Try giving this a read:

http://spu.fem.uniag.sk/cvicenia/ksov/hanova/Econometrics%20I/matrices2.pdf

Comment: at 2rare2die did you read the question before typing an answer? of course excel will populate the formula when you drag the cell dah! the question is how to drag vertically and horizontally and still get accurate numbers. I used X1 and X2 just to illustrate the formula.

Comment: I did read the question, but I wasn't totally sure if you were really new at Excel or not.  To be fair it wasn't 100% clear, the x and y in the formula definitely threw me off and you didn't specify what was expected but what resulted instead.  However, look at my edited answer.  Excel has functions for matrix arithmetic. I referenced a simple multiplication one. Perhaps there's another one that can do custom operations and autofill your formulas.  Not a complete answer, but maybe helpful?  Maybe reword the question if I'm still just totally off base.